# get data between first day and last day of month of selected date

Tags: sql

**how to get data between first day and last day of specific month in SQL?**

Following is the sql query please help

```
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
SELECT @mydate = GETDATE()
select TransactionCode from ReceiptsPayments 
where ReferenceDate >= (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),
                                       DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)-1),@mydate),
                                       101) AS Date_Value)
  AND ReferenceDate <= (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),
                                       DATEADD(dd,
                                               -(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate))),
                                               DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate)),
                                       101))
GO
```

Comment: if you want DATA for specific month then put month in where clause only like
where month(ReferenceDate) = month(ReferenceDate)

Comment: What is the type of `ReferenceDate`?

Comment: @chetan: A query that selects on a date column being between two values may be able to make use of an index on that column - your query would not be able to make use of such an index.

Comment: ***WHAT*** database system is this for? SQL is just the query language, used by **many** database systems. And stuff like date handling is highly vendor-specific - so are you using MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server? IBM DB2? Postgres? Something else? If so: whta??

Comment: `GETDATE()`, `CONVERT` and `DATEADD` make it highly likely that this is SQL Server, but as marc_s says, please add a specific tag to your question.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
SELECT @mydate = GETDATE()

SELECT TransactionCode 
FROM dbo.ReceiptsPayments 
WHERE MONTH(ReferenceDate) = MONTH(@mydate) 
    AND YEAR(ReferenceDate) = YEAR(@mydate)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select TransactionCode 
from ReceiptsPayments 
where 
month(ReferenceDate) = month(@mydate) 
and 
year(ReferenceDate) = year(@mydate) ;
```

Comment: You answered a first. Good one.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME 
SELECT @mydate = GETDATE() 

select TransactionCode 
  from ReceiptsPayments 
 where ReferenceDate >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @mydate), 0)
   and ReferenceDate <= DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @mydate) + 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

My own take use the `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` pattern:

```
select TransactionCode from ReceiptsPayments
where
    ReferenceDate >= DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',GETDATE()),'20010101') and
    ReferenceDate <= DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',GETDATE()),'20010131')
```

It's a bit cute because when it's asked to add a number of months onto the 31st of any month, it automatically adjusts to the correct end date of the month it arrives at.

Also, if there are times in your column, a better query would be:

```
select TransactionCode from ReceiptsPayments
where
    ReferenceDate >= DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',GETDATE()),'20010101') and
    ReferenceDate < DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',GETDATE()),'20010201')
```

Which is then using the 1st of the following month and performing a `<` comparison. This is usually better for `datetime`s with time components.